# Text Representation of RDF with turtle

Tags: rdf, turtle-rdf

I want to make a textual representations of an RDF graph with Turtle. As an example the relation between Spiderman and the Green Goblin. See the reference here https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/

```
@base <http://example.org/> .
@prefix rdf: <http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#> .
@prefix rdfs: <http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#> .
@prefix foaf: <http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/> .
@prefix rel: <http://www.perceive.net/schemas/relationship/> 

<#green-goblin>
    rel:enemyOf <#spiderman> ;
    a foaf:Person ;    # in the context of the Marvel universe
    foaf:name "Green Goblin" .
<#spiderman>
    rel:enemyOf <#green-goblin> ;
    a foaf:Person ;
    foaf:name "Spiderman", "Человек-паук"@ru .
```

What does the comma (`,`) mean between "Spiderman" and the Russian word?

Another more important question is: how can I do that with a city and a country over time? For example: Leipzig belonged to the DDR until 1990. Today Leipzig is a city in Germany.

Comment: How can you do _what_ with a city and a country over time? It's not very clear what you're after, or what your "other question" has to do with your example of Spiderman and the Green Goblin.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seems like two very separate questions here.  One on syntax and one on modeling.

For the syntax problem I'd suggest looking at [Turtle - Terse RDF Triple Language](https://www.w3.org/TR/2014/REC-turtle-20140225/).  Turtle specifies triples, which requires three entities in the specification of a triple.  The `.` specifies the end of a triple.  As a shortcut, a `;` means the current *subject* is carried over to the next triple specification - hence only the predicate and object need to be specified.  A `,` means the *subject* and *object* are carried over to the next triple.  Therefore,

```
<#spiderman> foaf:name "Spiderman", "Человек-паук"@ru .
```

Specifies two triples:

```
<#spiderman> foaf:name "Spiderman" .
<#spiderman> foaf:name "Человек-паук"@ru .
```

One the modeling question, to specify the different nationalizations of Leipzig at different epochs of time, specify a property, such as `isMemberOfCountry` that has properties of `fromDate` and `toDate`.  Each instance of country membership would then be populated:

```
@prefix ex: <http://example.org/geoex/> 
ex:Leipzig
  ex:isMemberOfCountry [
      ex:country ex:DDR ;
      ex:fromDate 1945 ;
      ex:toDate 1990 ;
    ] ;
  ex:isMemberOfCountry [
      ex:country ex:Germany ;
      ex:fromDate 1990 ;
    ] .
```

Bnodes are used ensure unique names across the dataset for an object whose name may not matter (if it does, then specify an object a use in place of the bnode).  Then to query the current country, use:

```
SELECT ?country
WHERE {
   ex:Leipzig ex:isMemberOfCountry ?member .
   ?member ex:country ?country .
   FILTER NOT EXISTS {
      ?member ex:toDate ?d
   }
}
```

And to find the membership during a specific year, use the following:

```
SELECT ?country
WHERE {
 BIND("1991"^^xsd:integer AS ?date) #placeholder - ?date should be passed into the query
    ex:Leipzig ex:isMemberOfCountry ?member .
    ?member ex:country ?country .
    ?member ex:fromDate ?fdate .
    OPTIONAL {?member ex:toDate ?td}
    BIND(IF(bound(?td), ?td, year(now())) AS ?edate)
    FILTER (?date >= ?fdate && ?date <= ?edate)
}
```

Note that binding `?date` to 1990 will result in two results, which is correct given that years are used instead of dates in this example model.

Comment: Ok, that helps a lot, thank you for the detailed informations. The tags or words like isMemberOfCountry or country are free defined tags. which are should be used in a logic way or ?

Comment: Those words are not "words" but URIs - objects.  So given the prefix definition above, ex:isMemberOfCountry expands to <http://example.org/geoex/isMemberOfCountry>.  Some research into the RDF/Turtle documents we've both posted here should make this clearer.

Comment: Note that Turtle is a W3C Recommendation: https://www.w3.org/TR/turtle/ (your link is to an older draft)

Comment: Thanks, I had simply grabbed the wrong URL.  Now corrected.